# Css transition on navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to put a transition to my navbar and i don't have an idea what to do. As you can see to the picture, i want to put a color below to a link like the "HOME" when hover the yellow color will appear and when it hover to another link it will dissappear and the other will appear. How can i do this? Give me some ideas please.

Here is my html code.

```
             <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            </button>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/brandz.png" >
        </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                             <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header">
                                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                     <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

here is my css code.

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #949494;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px 5px 60px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    line-height: 97px;


    }
    .navbar-default{
    background-color:#fff;

    }
    .nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    }
   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin:0 0 4px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;

    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive{
     width: 300px;
     height:50px;
     padding-left:50px;
     }
     }
     @media (max-width: 376px) {
     .img-responsive{
     width: 220px;
     height:50px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     }
     } 
     @media (max-width: 286px) {
     .img-responsive{
     width: 180px;
     height:50px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     }
     }
```

Comment: Plz Create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Im noob to css and html. i don't know what jsfiddle is sir sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a border bottom. Set it to transparent by default, give it an transition and fade it in on `:hover` for example.

https://jsfiddle.net/n6uz5yj3/1/

Comment: Thankyouuuuu sir! :) Cheers.

Comment: in the fiddle, line 18 of the CSS:
`border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;` - the `2px` is the thickness, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want is for the text to go yellow on hover, then
add this code:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

I've created the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/Lpdyqoy7/

You can also add a transition to make it look a bit cooler ( I've set it to orange in the fiddle to really see the difference) :

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/Lpdyqoy7/1/

And with the "line underneath":

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/Lpdyqoy7/2/

Comment: i want the yellow color below the link ma'am.

Comment: and a border beneath it

Comment: Thanks for the effort ma'am :")

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple snippet of what I think you're trying to achieve.

```css
ul {
  background: #3366FF;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #33FF66;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #33FF66;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Students</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Faculty</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort :)